# Passing PowerShell variables to filepath

Tags: powershell, variables

Completely new to Powershell but not new to programming. Anyway, Im trying to edit this script that was already created and it is almost working. I dont understand how to make Powershell pass a user assigned variable into the filepath for my invoke-command (`\MICROS\Res\pos\scripts\$ScriptName`) . Any help you can offer will be greatly appricated.

```
#Gather user input for name of script
$ScriptName=Read-Host "Enter the name of the script that you want to run [Examples: HH_Off.bat]"

#Loop through store array
foreach ($CurrentStore in $store) { #START LOOP
#How to call current store Name: $CurrentStore.Name
#How to call current store IP: $CurrentStore.IP
#How to call current store City: $CurrentStore.City
if ($RunListArray -contains $CurrentStore.ID){ #If the current store is in the input list
Write-Host " *** "$CurrentStore.City"("$CurrentStore.Name")"
$NetworkDrivePath = "\\" + $CurrentStore.IP + "\D$"

#Create Network Drives
New-PSDrive -Name $CurrentStore.Name -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $NetworkDrivePath -credential $mycred

#Check if site is responding
If (Test-Path -Path $NetworkDrivePath)
{
Write-Host " *** *** NETWORK DRIVE FOUND!!! PROCEEDING..."
Invoke-Command {powershell.exe -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass \MICROS\Res\pos\scripts\$ScriptName} -computername $CurrentStore.IP -credential $mycred

#REMOVE PS DRIVE
Remove-PSDrive $CurrentStore.Name
}
Else {
Write-Host " *** *** NETWORK DRIVE NOT FOUND, SENDING ERROR EMAIL"
$Subject = "*Testing*Powershell Error Send Files Script" + $CurrentStore.Name + " (" + $CurrentStore.City + ")"
$Body = "Network path " + $NetworkDrivePath + " is not accessible."
SendErrorEmail $Subject $Body
}
} #END LOOP
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is defined in the local (calling) session and not in the remote (Invoke-Command) session. It's referred to as scope. You can reach into the calling scope with the variable modifier `$using:` like this

```
Invoke-Command {powershell.exe -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass \MICROS\Res\pos\scripts\$using:ScriptName} -computername $CurrentStore.IP -credential $mycred
```

Or as a named or unnamed parameter with `-ArgumentList`

```
#named parameter
Invoke-Command {Param($script)powershell.exe -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass \MICROS\Res\pos\scripts\$script} -computername $CurrentStore.IP -credential $mycred -ArgumentList $ScriptName

#unnamed parameter
Invoke-Command {powershell.exe -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass \MICROS\Res\pos\scripts\$args[0]} -computername $CurrentStore.IP -credential $mycred -ArgumentList $ScriptName
```

Formatted and using splatting for readability

```
$sb = {
    Param($script)
    powershell.exe -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass \MICROS\Res\pos\scripts\$script
}

$params = @{
    ScriptBlock  = $sb
    ComputerName = $CurrentStore.IP
    Credential   = $mycred
    ArgumentList = $ScriptName
}

Invoke-Command @params
```

Also you probably can and should avoid the extra call to powershell.exe.